# Checkbox as button

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

I trying use SLDS Lightning design system at a checkbox. My checkboxes should look like as button and when I click on it I try change background color. 
[image]For example: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#flavor-checkbox

I try edit below code:

```
<div aura:id="xcont" class="background-silver">
     <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="x" label="label" click={!c.voidJS}" class="line" />
</div>
```

To something like this

```
<span class="slds-button slds-checkbox--button" for="monday">
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="monday" />
  <label class="slds-checkbox--button__label" for="monday">
    <span class="slds-checkbox--faux">Mon</span>
  </label>
 </span>
```

but I don't know how I should void JS function when I click at checkbox.

Comment: you should try to use toggle button hope this work https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/forms/#flavor-checkbox-toggle

Comment: I do this and edited my question with the answear

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer. Not in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at forum and still learning.

Comment: Can I change style when I check checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I do this with below code - maybe someone use this:**

```
<div aura:id="xcont" class="slds-button slds-checkbox--button background-silver">
  <label class="answears slds-checkbox--button__label">
  <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="x" label="label" click={!c.voidJS}" class="line" />
</label>
</div>
```